# > Could not determine the dependencies of null. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1

Tags: react-native, gradle, java-8, java-11

I am trying to create a new project on react native with react-native cli but I wonder why this exception is being thrown(I assume has to do with the JDK being used or something similar)

the exception is :

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.

this si my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_X
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_X
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

on my app folder

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

react {
    
}

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.firstrnapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firstrnapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
 buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.4.0"

}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1')
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: i just installed the latest react native cli, got almost similar issue. try to run this command `npx react-native doctor` and share the output please.

Answer (score 3):

After Installing latest React Native 0.72 and latest Android Studio Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2, I got very similar issue.

Although I'm not 100% sure what is the exact source of the issue, **I fixed it by doing the following**:

#1: set proper JAVA_HOME path to latest JDK you have. You can run this command to open Environment Variables Editor in windows 10 Terminal/CMD: `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`. Then, add/edit JAVA_HOME variable like this:

[image: JAVA_HOME]

Also, I used to have multiple java version in the path, i removed all of theme from the path!

#2 In root folder of the project run `npx react-native doctor`, it displays some useful information like this:

[image: npx react-native doctor]

*** Note that I clicked `e` here. I don't know if it helped me fixing the issue ***

#3 According to this I have to make sure to install Android SDK Command-line Tools version 33.0.0. -notice this number can different based on the version React version you are using- Open Android Studio Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools Tab.

Enable Show Package Details checkbox.

[image: show details]

Download the proper version of SDK Command-line Tools, in my case it is 33.0.0 :

[image: sdk-tools]

#4 close all opened Terminal/CMD windows.

#5 In root folder of the project open terminal and run the following commands:

*5.1 `cd android`

*5.2 `gradlew --stop` -make sure it stops without prompting an error-

*5.3 `gradlew` -it should say BUILD SUCCESSFUL-

*5.4 `gradlew clean` -it should say BUILD SUCCESSFUL-

6. That was it, you just need to go back to root folder using `cd ..` and run project using `npm start`.

Comment: @Nick it looks like self-hosting of the images, which is no so bad. I agree that the official image provider should be used.

Comment: @mozway you are indeed correct; I have to confess I didn't look past the URL part. I'll retract the comment

Comment: If anyone flagged this as spam because of my original comment, please retract that. I apologise for my stuff-up.

Comment: @nick my reputation was low i could't post the imgs sorry.

Comment: @AlBaash247 my apologies again for my mistake, I should have paid more attention to what was in the links. I'm glad to see all the flags have been removed.